# The service call is returning the function definition than the actual return in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, service, angularjs-scope

Here in summary.controller.js at line 37 i'm calling the 'filter.jdpa' which is the method defined in the service: filter.js.
The method is meant to return an array jdpaarr but when i call it in the controller i get the whole method definition as the output
[image: The output of the controller]

[image: The service calls from the controller]

The code for the service is also attached below

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app')
            .service('filter', filter);

    function filter() {

            this.jdpaf=jdpaf;
            this.yearf=yearf;
            this.cityf=cityf;

    function jdpaf(){
         var jdpaarr=['All','JDPA','Non-JDPA'];
         console.log(jdpaarr);
        return 'jdpaarr';


    }

    function yearf(){
        var yeararr=['2011','2012','2013','2014'];
            console.log(yeararr);
        return 'yeararr';
    }


    function cityf(){
        var cityarr=['Delhi','Mumbai','Trivandrum','Banglore','Hyderabad'];
        return cityarr;
    }


        }
    })();
```

I have given console.logs in the service itself but that fails to work.
But why is the whole function definition being shown in the function call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically assigning the definition only.

Try calling/executing it on initialization and saving the returned value in your scope like.

```
$scope.Filterarray.jdpa = filter.jdpaf();
```

Hope this helps.